# MySQL: Set variable and use in where clause in same query

Tags: mysql

I'm having some trouble setting a user variable in MySQL and using it in the same query.  I found one or two other questions similar to this, but couldn't get any of their solutions to work in my case.

Here's my query, stripped down a bit.  I replaced values and names and stuff for simplicity, and removed some irrelevant parts, but left the basic structure for some context. Not really relevant but fyi I'm using CodeIgniter's active record class to build the query.

```
SELECT * FROM (things, (SELECT @exp_time := IF(5 < 10, X, Y) as var))
JOIN more_things ON ...
WHERE ...
AND @exp_time < UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
AND `@exp_time` > 1319180316
ORDER BY ...
LIMIT 1 ...
```

The error I'm getting is: "Every derived table must have its own alias."

Would really appreciate any assistance.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your actual error is because (as the error message explains) you haven't specified an alias for your derived table, and this is *required* in MySQL (even if you never use the alias anywhere else in your query).

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    things,
    (SELECT @exp_time := IF(5 < 10, X, Y) as var) AS your_alias
)                 
...
```

However you don't need variables here. Now that your derived table actually has a name you have a way to refer to your value without needing to store it an a variable.

Comment: Hmm, now it's saying that my 'things' table doesn't exist ("unknown table "things"), but it definitely does.  When you say I don't need variables here, you means i could just copy the @exp_time code into both spots it's needed?  Thought this would be cleaner, but I guess it might not be worth the time figuring it out?

Comment: @G. Moore: You don't need a variable because it has a name (that's what the alias is for).

Comment: Ok.. could you perhaps show explicitly with this example what that would look like (i.e. no variable, just using the alias)? I gave it a shot but I'm not getting it...definitely a MySql novice, please forgive me!

Comment: Ah think I got it - need to use having instead of where to get the alias recognized, does that sound right?

Comment: @G. Moore: Having would work. You could also use a subselect: `SELECT * FROM (SELECT foo AS your_alias, .....) T1 WHERE T1.your_alias = 20`